# how to connect to office 365 outlook calender using javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, outlook, office365

how can i connect to office 365 using REST API from visual studio project,
from past one week i was trying to connect  office 365 using its API

```
function accessO365() {
    alert("Acces O365 method called");
    var authContext;
    var authToken; // for use with creating an outlookClient later.
    authContext = new O365Auth.Context();
    authContext.getIdToken("https://outlook.office365.com/")
       .then((function (token) {
           authToken = token;
           // The auth token also carries additional information. For example:    
           userName = token.givenName + " " + token.familyName;
       }).bind(this), function (reason) {
           console.log('Failed to login. Error = ' + reason.message);
       });
    // Once the authToken has been acquired, create an outlookClient. One place to do this is inside of the
    //    ".then" function callback of authContext.getIdToken(...) above.
    var outlookClient = new Microsoft.OutlookServices.Client('https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0', authToken.getAccessTokenFn('https://outlook.office365.com'));
    outlookClient.me.events.getEvents().fetch().then(function (result) {
        result.currentPage.forEach(function (event) {
            console.log('Event "' + event.subject + '"')
        });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

this was the code i was using previously in VS project but it is showing as undefined o365auth?
how can i resolve this and is there any better way to connect to office 365 using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to access calender events using unified o365 api:

// The code sample below demonstrates how to get events using the Office 365 unified API (Preview).

```
$.ajax('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/Events', {
        headers: { 
           Authorization: 'Bearer {token:https://graph.microsoft.com/}',
            Accept: 'application/json;odata.metadata=none',
    }
}).then(function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.value.length; i++) {
            console.log('Event "' + response.value[i].Subject + '"');
        }
        console.log('\n' + 'Full JSON response:')
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Before getting the events, make sure that you have a valid access token.

Here is an oauth sandbox where you can test your requests:

https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/

Hope this helps.